# Constrained d3.js Force display

Tags: graph, d3.js, timeline, force-layout

I'd like to do something a little bit out of the ordinary with force layouts (for visualizing graphs). Constellations and all are fun to look at, but for timeseries data, it's not that helpful. I'd like to be able to constrain the layout by some axis, for example, by laying out the nodes according to the time they appear in a dataset, while still retaining the "bouncyness" of the visualization. Is this possible using d3?

Comment: Yes, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100060/d3-js-force-directed-layout-constrained-by-a-shape) should give you some pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, yes, this is perfectly possible. The force layout does not in fact position the nodes itself, it merely computes the positions. In the handler of the `tick` event you usually provide the function that takes care of the positioning. There, you can add arbitrary constraints that restrict how the nodes can move.

Taking one of the [stock examples](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), you could do things like the following to restrict the x coordinate to within +-10 of the intended position with unrestricted y.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  node.each(function(d) {
    var intended = scale(d.value);
    d.x = d.px = Math.min(intended + 10, Math.max(intended - 10, d.px));
  });
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

Here is another [example](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/index-alt.html) that uses the force layout to position labels. There, the x position is ignored (i.e. constant) and only the y is affected by the layout.

Comment: Thank you, Lars! Can I ask, is: `var intended = scale(d.value)` supposed to be replaced by `var xpos = scale(d.date)` in my case, where datetime is the value on which I wish to put on my x-axis?

Comment: You haven't posted any code so I don't know what your variables are called but yes, this would designate the x position.

Comment: Thank you Lars! I was just able to test it out after fixing some other bugs in my code, and it works provisionally! Now to modify the scales to make sure it works properly. :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Webcola is a great tool for creating constraint-based layouts with D3.JS.

See https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola

Comment: Agreed, ***but*** beware of [WebCola Missing documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889372/webcola-missing-documentation)